Who are the guests, Revelation 19:9, to the wedding supper of the lamb?
THE WEDDING, who participates?
The bridegroom (JESUS) + The bride (CHURCH)
THE SUPPER, who participates?
The guests (?) - Who are they?
The Bride and the Bridegroom cannot be the Guests at the same time!
Texts:

“Then the kingdom of heaven will be like ten virgins who took their
lamps and went to meet the bridegroom.” - Matthew 25:1 ESV


“The one who has the bride is the bridegroom. The friend of the
bridegroom, who stands and hears him, rejoices greatly at the
bridegroom's voice. Therefore this joy of mine is now complete.” –
John 3:29 ESV


“Let us rejoice and exult and give him the glory, for the marriage of
the Lamb has come, and his Bride has made herself ready; it was
granted her to clothe herself with fine linen, bright and pure”— for
the fine linen is the righteous deeds of the saints. And the angel
said to me, “Write this: Blessed are those who are invited to the
marriage supper of the Lamb.” And he said to me, “These are the true
words of God.” – Revelation 19:7-9 ESV


We usually included the text of any scriptural citations for the convenience of our readers, Ricardo. I've gone ahead and completed this for you.

Not the Church itself, but the City Where God's Saints will Dwell
The Book of Revelation adopts the metaphor of the prophet Jeremiah, who spoke of Jerusalem as God's bride.
Jeremiah 2:2

Go, cry out this message for Jerusalem to hear! I remember the
devotion of your youth, how you loved me as a bride, Following me in
the wilderness, in a land unsown.

Thus, in Revelation 21:2 we read:

I also saw the holy city, a new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven
from God, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband.

Jerusalem was not synonymous with the people of Israel was their holy city. Thus, the bride is the restored holy city, not the congregation of saints. This becomes even more plain when we read more of chapter 21:

“Come here. I will show you the bride, the wife of the Lamb.” 10 He
took me in spirit to a great, high mountain and showed me the holy
city Jerusalem coming down out of heaven from God. 11 It gleamed with
the splendor of God. Its radiance was like that of a precious stone,
like jasper, clear as crystal. 12 It had a massive, high wall, with
twelve gates where twelve angels were stationed and on which names
were inscribed, [the names] of the twelve tribes of the Israelites. 13
There were three gates facing east, three north, three south, and
three west. 14 The wall of the city had twelve courses of stones as
its foundation, on which were inscribed the twelve names of the twelve
apostles of the Lamb.

This is a place - whether on earth or in the spiritual realm - where the saints enter and dwell. It is not the congregation of the saints (the church) but the place God has prepared for them to occupy. Thus we are told:

The nations will walk by its light, and to it the kings of the earth
will bring their treasure. 25 During the day its gates will never be
shut, and there will be no night there... (chapter 22) The throne of
God and of the Lamb will be in it, and his servants will worship him.

As to who are the people invited, they are those who have passed through the trials described in the previous chapters, leading up the fall of Babylon in 17-18.
Conclusion: In the Book of Revelation, the "bride" is the new Jerusalem.  Because Revelation is open to so many interpretations, I will not go further in order to avoid theological speculation. However, the text makes it clear that the bride is the new Jerusalem and those invited are those who have gone through what has been described in earlier chapters. As long was one distinguishes between the new Jerusalem and those invited, the problem presented by the OP is resolved. The "bride" is the city; those invited to the wedding are those who will enter it (Rev. 21:7).

+1 Insightful comment as a result of careful reading of related scriptures. Thank you! The bride is clothed by the righteous deeds of the saints (Revelation 19:8). This is also apparent in Mark 2:19 ESV, "And Jesus said to them, “Can the wedding guests fast while the bridegroom is with them? As long as they have the bridegroom with them, they cannot fast." After the Bridegroom is gone, they will fast according to Mark 2:20.

I can't claim certainty about this, but I do think that the symbol of the Bride is used in different senses. Sometimes it does mean believers (or the church) but in this particular case it is the wonderful city where true believers will enter and live.

A city as a corporate or composite bridal identity versus individuals is important, especially for those of us who are staunchly masculine. I find that a bearded image of myself smoking a cigar and wearing army boots is more than a little ridiculous in a wedding dress!

But... although I argue for the bride being the city in this case, I don't have a problem with the idea of being part of the corporate entity that is called God's wife/bride. Both the NT and the OT use this symbol. I think of it in the sense that both genders are responsive/receptive  to God love. He fills us, not the other way around (at least at first).

For those who see some discontinuity between Israel and the Church (including Dispensationalists, but not only them), in the Bible's metaphorical depictions of the wedding of Christ and the Church, the guests may be identified with Israel. Israel related to God on the basis of their covenant with him, and received salvation when they were faithful to God, but they did not have a direct relationship with Christ in particular in the way that Christians do. In this perspective there is something distinctly special about how Christ came to choose and bind a people to himself, something that Israel would be there to celebrate.
But this is only a metaphorical depiction. We have to remember that Israel's relationship with God was also depicted as a marriage in the Old Testament. And even though the OT saints were saved without knowledge of the incarnate Jesus, in the new heavens and new earth they will still know Jesus as Christians do, because the purpose and endpoint of God's revelations before Christ was to prepare people to know Christ.

O really??  You want a literal wedding??  The book of Revelation is a highly symbolic book with lots of non-literal things described!  For example we have:

Rev 1 - Jesus walking among lampstands that represent churches.  Jesus holds seven stars in His hand representing the angels/messengers to the churches.  Jesus has bronze feet, etc.  None of this is literal!
Rev 5 - Jesus is first a lion, then a tree root, and then a bleeding lamb with seven horns and seven eyes.  He is surrounded by four animals, a lion, a ox, one with a human face and an eagle.  None of this is literal!
Rev 6 - horses and riders come out of a scroll in the hand God and Jesus.  None of this is literal!
Rev 10 - John eats a scroll tasing like honey
Rev 11 - two witness are two trees and two prophets that breath fire!  Then they are overpowered by a beast climbing out of the earth.  None of this is literal!
Rev 12 - a pregnant woman clothed in the sun with the moon under her feet wearing a crown of 12 stars attacked by a giant snake and dragon with seven heads.  None of this is literal!
Rev 13 - two more mythical, unreal beasts.  None of this is literal!
Rev 14 - 144,000 lead by a lamb with writing on their foreheads.  None of this is literal!
etc

We must recall the opening verse of the symbolic book:

Rev 1:1 - The revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave Him to show
to His bond-servants what things it behooves to take place in
quickness. And He signified it through having sent His angel to
His servant, John

Thus, the book itself tells us that the text is written in signs and symbols as it is signified.
Now, back to Rev 19, which is, again, in highly symbolic language.  The symbols do not have to make literal sense; that is not their purpose.  Their purpose is to teach truth via the medium (in modern terms) of cartoons.
[To use a modern analogy, the film the Lion King is not literally true but teaches important truths about human nature and politics.]
Thus, in Rev 19, it is not a logical necessity that saved & forgiven saints who comprise the "bride" of the Lamb, cannot also be guests in this symbolic narrative.  However, it is also not essential either.  This is because "those invited" are not necessarily guests, but simply those invited to be part of the bride of the Lamb.
Simple really!

I respect your interpretation! However, despite the book of Revelation being a book of super symbolism, these same symbols have a literal meaning and do not mix with each other, therefore in Revelation 19, Groom is Groom, Bride is Bride, Guests is Guest, all under the same category: SAVED.

@RicardoBarros - What makes you ASSUME that the invited people are guests as distinct from members of God's church, the Bride of the Lamb.  That ASSUMPTION is not based on the text!

It's not me who makes the distinction, it's the text itself that says there is a groom, a bride, and the groom's friends (the guests)

@RicardoBarros - the words "friends" or "guests" do not appear anywhere in the text.  All that is said is of "those invited".

And Καὶ he says λέγει to me μοι Write Γράψον Blessed [are] Μακάριοι those οἱ to εἰς the τὸ supper δεῖπνον of the τοῦ marriage γάμου of the τοῦ Lamb Ἀρνίου having been invited κεκλημένοι And καὶ he says λέγει to me μοι These Οὗτοι the οἱ words λόγοι TRUE ἀληθινοὶ  -  τοῦ of God Θεοῦ are εἰσιν

@RicardoBarros - correct - no "friends" or "guests".  Only those invited to become part of the marriage to the Lamb.

Friend, it doesn't matter! The texts make a distinction between bride, groom, and guests. When you know the correct answer, just say so! Rest in peace.

@RicardoBarros - that is simply untrue - there is no such distinction.  But you may believe what you will.

you can think whatever you want.
The texts contain three distinct symbols with distinct meanings..

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
